# How do I pass a searchstring to perform a search?

Tags: javascript, jquery

again I'm stuck and asking you to help me.

I want to enter a search string in an input-field. The search string should perform a search like https://.../=~searchstring

The textfield:

```
$("<input id='field-inputSearchString' type='text' name='field_inputSearchString'>").insertAfter('.completed ticket');
```

I've got two questions here:

1. I guess I need to 'find' the string to pass it to the search link. Is it sth. like this?
   `$(function() {
   var foundin = $('input[id$='field-inputSearchString']:contains(text)');
   });`
2. And how do I pass the text to the link? Have you got an example or link explaining what I'm looking for?

I appreciate every help. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: are you trying to do it as a simple form or must it be AJAX?

Comment: It should be as simple as possible.

Comment: So when it should be simple, why dont you use a form? You can style a submit-button as if it is a hyperlink, there's no need to workaround with javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the value of an input field with id you can do

```
$("#field-inputSearchString").val();
```

You cannot use `:contains` because it searches for elements that contains the text.

If you want to pass the string to the href of an anchor tag

```
var href = $("#anchorID").attr("href");
$("#anchorID").attr("href", href + $("#field-inputSearchString").val());
```